# While + simple present vs simple progressive

Tags: grammaticality

I found the following sentence:

> While Mary recovers, John lets out a shriek.

Something about it makes me squirm, and I think it's the grammar.

I think it should be:

> While Mary is recovering, John lets out a shriek.

What do you think?

Comment: I think you should look elsewhere for the cause of your squirming.

Answer (score 1):

The simple present is rarely used (unless the action is habitual), but the original sentence would be fine as stage directions (in a play).

Comment: If it is used but rarely, I wonder what nuance of meaning using simple present conveys...

Comment: Your passive simple present 'is used', and active simple present 'wonder', are both habitual (so not rare).  'He wins races' is habitual, but non-habitual 'He wins the race' is rare, unless it is a (news) commentary.